# How to parse data using REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regex-greedy

I have a data set like this (see below) and I try to extract digits which are in form {variable_number_of_digits}{hyphen}{only_one_digit}:

```
with mcte as (
select 'ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH' as addr from dual
union all 
select 'ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG' as addr from dual
union all
select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/' as addr  from dual
union all
select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE' as addr from dual
)
select  addr, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'(\/)([0-9-]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS num1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'(\/)([^\/]+\/)([0-9\-]+)',1,1,NULL,3) num2
from mcte
;
```

I'm not getting a correct results set which should be the following

```
+-------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                ADDR                 |   NUM1    |   NUM2    |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH      | NULL      | NULL      |
| ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG | NULL      | NULL      |
| IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/          | 1573230-0 | 2216755-7 |
| IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE   | 1573230-0 | NULL      |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: So num1's position isn't important, it's just the first number with the correct format even if in another position in the data?

Comment: Yes, position in the string is not important, it is just the first occurrence between "/ /".

Comment: Could there be something like .../34400-0-3009/... - and if so, should it be picked up or not? (I assume not; you want the single digit to be right before /). More importantly, what about .../34400-2003-5/...  - do you want THAT picked up? Or perhaps just 2003-5? Or not al all?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sorry I misundestood your question, the order of the numbers is important so that if num1 is NOT in the desired format but num2 IS, num1 should be null and num2 the number from the second number.

Comment: @jrara You may want to clarify with an example. You're saying that with the example `IIODK/TEST/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE` both I (that put 1573230-0 as the first match as num1) and MT0 (that put it in column2 since it's after the second slash) are wrong? What would be the expected result then?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The expected result is attached to my question. So, 1573230-0 should match and return 1573230-0 to num1 but 2216755-700 does not match (because it has -700, not just -7) at it should return NULL to num2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the results from the second and third `/` delimited groups then:

```
with mcte ( addr ) as (
  select 'ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH'      from dual union all 
  select 'ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG' from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/'          from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE'   from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/TEST/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE'   from dual
)
select  addr, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'^[^/]*/(\d+-\d)/',1,1,NULL,1) AS num1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'^[^/]*/[^/]*/(\d+-\d)/',1,1,NULL,1) num2
from mcte;
```

**Output**:

```
ADDR                                   NUM1                NUM2
-------------------------------------- ------------------- -------------------
ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH
ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG
IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/             1573230-0           2216755-7
IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE      1573230-0
IIODK/TEST/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE                     1573230-0
```

**Update**:

If you just want the first and second pattern that match and do not care where they are in the string then:

```
with mcte ( addr ) as (
  select 'ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH'         from dual union all 
  select 'ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG'    from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/'             from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE'      from dual union all
  select 'IIODK/TEST/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE' from dual union all
  select '1234567-8'                              from dual union all
  select '1234567-8/9876543-2'                    from dual union all
  select '1234567-8/TEST/9876543-2'               from dual
)
select  addr, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'(^|/)(\d+-\d)(/|$)',1,1,NULL,2) AS num1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(addr,'(^|/)\d+-\d(/.+?)?/(\d+-\d)(/|$)',1,1,NULL,3) num2
from mcte;
```

**Outputs**:

```
ADDR                                   NUM1                NUM2

-------------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------
ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH
ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG
IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/             1573230-0           2216755-7
IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE      1573230-0
IIODK/TEST/1573230-0/2216755-700/WRITE 1573230-0           
1234567-8                              1234567-8
1234567-8/9876543-2                    1234567-8           9876543-2
1234567-8/TEST/9876543-2               1234567-8           9876543-2
```

Comment: This shouldn't work: if num1 is not in the desired format, but num2 is, then num2 will be presented as num1 (because .* will eat up the / and all of num1 and will pick up num2 under the AS num1 part).

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, fixed

Comment: Good! I posted my solution but since it is now identical to yours, I removed it.   Cheers,   mahtguy

Comment: This does not seem to give the correct result. For the last ADDR the number is in the wrong column (in NUM2), it should be in NUM1.

Comment: @jrara You said in the comments that it should be, `num1`in the last row would be `TEST` and not in the correct format, so it should be NULL and  `num2` (1573230-0)  should be displayed?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No, you have misunderstood, I do not care about the text in the string, only the order of the numbers is essential, NUM1 and NUM2 only for numbers, in the correct order, and if the numbers does not match the {variable_number_of_digits}{hyphen}{only_one_digit}, it should return null.

Comment: @jrara Added an update - next time please make sure that your question is explicit as to how the result should be calculated as both my solutions are answers to your question but with different assumptions (which I state in the pre-amble to each solution) which you question is ambiguous about.

Comment: @MT0 Suberp! Now it works as expected. Sorry for not clarifying myself clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to extract digits which are in form {variable_number_of_digits}{hyphen}{only_one_digit}

To match numbers in this format you should do something like this.

**Regex:** `\/\d+-\d`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA5gZ6/1)**

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it does not give the correct results.

Comment: Try with `[0-9]` instead of `\d`. What output are you getting ? Any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the [**delimiter split query**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601828/how-to-select-values-within-a-column/31606666#31606666) with `REGEXP_LIKE` and *pivot*-ing the result you get this query working for up to 6 numbers. You will need to update the `cols` subquery  and teh `pivot` list to be able to process more numbers per record. (Unfortunately this can't be done general in a static SQL).

```
with mcte as (
  select 1 id, 'ILLD/ELKJS/00000000/ELKJS/FHSH' as addr from dual
  union all 
  select 2 id, 'ILLD/EFECTE/0116988-7-002/ADFA/ADFG' as addr from dual
  union all
  select 3 id, 'IIODK/1573230-0/2216755-7/' as addr  from dual
  union all
  select 4 id, '1-1/1573230-0/2216755-700/676-7' as addr from dual
),
cols as (select  rownum colnum from dual connect by level < 6 /* (max) number of columns */),
mcte2 as (select id, cols.colnum, (regexp_substr(addr,'[^/]+', 1, cols.colnum)) addr 
              from mcte, cols where regexp_substr(addr, '[^/]+', 1, cols.colnum) is not null),
mcte3 as (              
select ID, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by COLNUM) as col_no, ADDR from mcte2
where REGEXP_like(addr, '^[0-9]+-[0-9]$')
)
select * from mcte3
PIVOT (max(addr)   for (col_no) in 
     (1 as "NUM1",
      2 as "NUM2",
      3 as "NUM3",
      4 as "NUM4",
      5 as "NUM5",
      6 as "NUM6"))
order by id;
```

this gives a result

```
        ID NUM1       NUM2       NUM3       NUM4       NUM5       NUM6     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3 1573230-0  2216755-7                                              
         4 1-1        1573230-0  676-7
```