# How to select the most matching subString to another String

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, string-matching

Lets say the full String is

> The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas

and the subString is

> substing bounded

is there any way that I could check the full string if contains a 90% matching subString  using sql

like the word ***substing bounded*** and ***substring bounded*** in my example

the subString could be a compound of more words so I can't split the full string into words .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First transform your text in a table of words. You'll find a lot as posts to this topic on SO, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601828/how-to-select-values-within-a-column/31606666#31606666)

You'll have to adjust the list of delimiter characters to extract the words only.

This is a sample query

```
 with t1 as (select 1 rn, 'The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas' col from dual  ),
      t2 as (select  rownum colnum from dual connect by level < 16 /* (max) number of words */),
      t3 as (select t1.rn, t2.colnum, rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^ ,]+', 1, t2.colnum)))  col  from t1, t2 
      where regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^ ,]+', 1, t2.colnum) is not null)
 select * from t3;

COL      
----------
The        
following  
example    
examines
...
```

In the next step your the [Levenshtein Distance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_MATCH.html#GUID-89D6DA9F-64B5-44D4-8CE4-5E412D56194B) to get the closes word.

```
 with t1 as (select 1 rn, 'The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas' col from dual  ),
      t2 as (select  rownum colnum from dual connect by level < 16 /* (max) number of words */),
      t3 as (select t1.rn, t2.colnum, rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^ ,]+', 1, t2.colnum)))  col  from t1, t2 
      where regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^ ,]+', 1, t2.colnum) is not null)
 select col, str, UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(col, str)  distance
 from t3
 cross join (select 'commas' str from dual)
 order by 3;

COL        STR      DISTANCE
---------- ------ ----------
comas      commas          1 
for        commas          5 
examines   commas          6 
...
```

Check the definition of the Levenshtein Distance and define a threshold on the distance to get your candidate words.

To **match independent of the word boundary** simple scan through your input and get all substring in a lenth of your match string adjusted for the diferentce e.g. adding some 10%.

You may limit the candidates by filtering such substrings only that start on the word boundary. The rest ist the same distance calculation.

```
 with txt as (select  'The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas' txt from dual),
      str as (select  'substing bounded' str from dual),
      t1 as (select  substr(txt, rownum, (select length(str) * 1.1 from str)) substr, /* add 10% length for the match */
                     (select str from str) str 
             from txt connect by level < (select length(txt) from txt) - (select length(str) from str)) 
 select SUBSTR, STR, 
        UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(SUBSTR, STR)  distance
 from t1
 order by 3;

SUBSTR               STR                DISTANCE
-------------------- ---------------- ----------
substring bounded    substing bounded          1 
ubstring bounded     substing bounded          3 
 substring bounde    substing bounded          3 
t substring bound    substing bounded          5 
...
```

Comment: I've edited the question .. the substring could be more than one word .

Comment: @Mohammad updated the answer with the most general solution ignoring the word boundary at all. You may adjust it to the solution you prefers.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the `SOUNDEX` function.

I haven't tested this but this might help you on your way:

```
    WITH strings AS (
      select regexp_substr('The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas','[ ]+', 1, level) ss 
      from dual
      connect by regexp_substr('The following example examines the string, looking for the first substring bounded by comas', '[ ]+', 1, level) is not null
    )
    SELECT ss 
    FROM strings
    WHERE SOUNDEX(ss) = SOUNDEX( 'commas' ) ;
```

The `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with `CONNECT BY` splits the long string into words (by space) - amend the delimited as required to include punctuation marks etc.

Here we are relying on the built-in `SOUNDEX` matching our expectations.

Comment: the substring could be more than one word

Comment: In all fairness the two answer you have been given should give you enough to able to do teh next step yourself. Both mine and Marmite Bomber's answers show how to split strings into separate words, so I would suggest you try to apply either method to the search words and then `JOIN` the two sets.

Comment: well , I'm working with arabic data which makes the soundex function useless .. the other answer works but the substring cant be spitted

Comment: You didn't mention Arabic in your question.

Comment: sorry for that :)