# Oracle: Paramterized Query with IN clause return null value

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

The Paramterized Query with IN clause is not working; it not able to replace the value

```
PROCEDURE p_getdata(A IN LONG,B IN LONG,C IN LONG, cur OUT c_data)
AS
l_query LONG;

   BEGIN
 IF C IS NULL THEN
open cur for  'select firstname, lastname, streetname, city
               from mytable 
               where zip IN(:A) AND streetnumber IN(:B) AND apt_num in(:C)' using A, B,C;

 END IF;
END;
```

here

```
       a ='202020';
        b='12','13','10','92','02','02'
        c='A','B'
```

In Db all datatype is varchar2. How to make it run and store the value is cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass the comma separated list as a parameter (bind variable), but you are responsible for parsing it in a subquery. A solution based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378083/comma-separated-list) uses regexp_substr.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE p_getdata(A IN VARCHaR2, cur OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
open cur for  'with t1 as (select :A col from dual),
     t2 as (select level lvl,to_number(regexp_substr(col,''[^,]+'', 1, level)) col 
              from t1 connect by regexp_substr(col, ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null)
select col as id from t2' using A;
END;
/
```

The procedure is simplified, but should provide a feeling how to use it.

The big advantage against the use of dynamic SQL (concatenation of strings) is that you need not parse the statement on each execution. Not to mention the security  (scare of SQL injection).

Usage:

```
DECLARE 
  l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_id NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  p_getdata('1,1000,282828,4',l_cur);
 LOOP
    FETCH l_cur INTO l_id ;
    EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_id);
 END LOOP;
END;
/


1
1000
282828
4
```

**UPDATE**

The above procedure is simplified, to get your functionality you should use a query like this in the CURSOR (i.e. first split all three parameters in separate subqueries using subquery factoring, than apply the results in your query)

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE p_getdata(A IN VARCHAR2, B in VARCHAR2, c in VARCHAR2, cur OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
open cur for  'with ta1 as (select :A col from dual),
     ta2 as (select level lvl,to_number(regexp_substr(col,''[^,]+'', 1, level)) col 
              from ta1 connect by regexp_substr(col, ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null),
 tb1 as (select :B col from dual),
     tb2 as (select level lvl,to_number(regexp_substr(col,''[^,]+'', 1, level)) col 
              from tb1 connect by regexp_substr(col, ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null),
 tc1 as (select :C col from dual),
     tc2 as (select level lvl,to_number(regexp_substr(col,''[^,]+'', 1, level)) col 
              from tc1 connect by regexp_substr(col, ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null)              
select firstname, lastname, streetname, city
from mytable 
where zip IN (select col from ta2) AND 
      streetnumber IN (select col from tb2) AND 
      apt_num in (select col from tc2)' using A, B, C;
END;
/
```

test passed

```
DECLARE 
  l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_firstname VARCHAR2(20);
  l_lastname VARCHAR2(20);
  l_streetname VARCHAR2(20);
  l_city VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN 
  p_getdata('1100,,1200','1,2','11,12' ,l_cur);
 LOOP
    FETCH l_cur INTO l_firstname, l_lastname, l_streetname, l_city;
    EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_firstname|| ' ' || l_lastname || ' ' || l_streetname  || ' ' || l_city);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the query **open cur for  'select firstname, lastname, streetname, city
               from mytable 
               where zip IN(:A) AND streetnumber IN(:B) AND apt_num in(:C)' using A, B,C;** its not replaced with the value

Comment: means :A , :B, :C paramter value not replaced

Comment: @Rajesh I expanded the answer

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply,  I m in edge of solution.

Comment: 1) with ta1 as (select  :A  col from dual)   2)tb1 as (select  :B  col from dual), 3) tc1 as (select  :C  col from dual), in this 3 lines I am getting Error as "Error(61,18): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'A'" same for :B and : C

Comment: @Rajesh I re-worked the example to be complete. But remember, you'll have to learn to handle *minor exceptions* independently:)

Comment: thanks alot. :) Thanks for ur effort. Thanks  Thanks  Thanks  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using parameters is to make the structure of the query separate from the data of the query.  When you make a placeholder, you've essentially made a promise that it will only ever represent *one* value, not a list of values.

In your case, *if you trust your data*, you'll need to use string concatenation and omit the `USING`:

```
OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT ... WHERE zip IN(' || A || ') AND ...';
```

Comment: Data not trustable. So they asked me to use only paramterized query to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
open cur for  select firstname, lastname, streetname, city
           from mytable 
           where zip (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(A,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND streetnumber IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(B,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(B, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND apt_num in(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(C,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(C, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL



It is working
```