# Fetch text between delimiter using regex in oracle

Tags: regex, database, oracle, oracle11g, expression

I'm getting a text oracle enclosed between delimiters. If possible, please help in creating a Regex for the text. I've an example of text

```
12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||
```

Till now I'm only able to fetch:

```
||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!
```

using this  `(\|\|(.*))+([^\|\|])`.

But I need this data to be separated from || and then split from !!. After which I need to save it into an array like this:

array[1]= (123,word1  ,word2, word3)

array[2]=(789,word4,word5  , word6)

array[3]=(2345  ,word7,word8, 890)

Comment: Try using **REGEXP_REPLACE** and match the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
with v1 as
(
  select '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||' t from dual
)
select level -1 id, trim(',' from regexp_replace(regexp_substr(t,'[^\|]+',1,level),'!!',',')) array from v1
where level > 1
connect by level <= regexp_count(t,'\|\|');
```

Output:

```
        ID ARRAY
---------- --------------------------
         1 123,word1  ,word2, word3
         2 789,word4,word5  , word6
         3 2345  ,word7,word8, 890
```

And if number of parts is constant (4) and You want them in separate columns:

```
with v1 as
(
      select '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||' t from dual
    ), v2 as
    (
    select level -1 id, trim(',' from regexp_replace(regexp_substr(t,'[^\|]+',1,level),'!!',',')) array
    from v1
    where level > 1
    connect by level <= regexp_count(t,'\|\|')
    )
    select id,
    regexp_substr(array,'[^,]+',1,1) val1,
    regexp_substr(array,'[^,]+',1,2) val2,
    regexp_substr(array,'[^,]+',1,3) val3,
    regexp_substr(array,'[^,]+',1,4) val4
    from v2;
```

Output:

```
        ID VAL1       VAL2       VAL3       VAL4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 123        word1      word2       word3
         2 789        word4      word5       word6
         3 2345       word7      word8       890
```

**PLSQL STYLE**:

```
declare 
  type t_text_array is table of varchar2(4000);
  v_text_array t_text_array := t_text_array();
  val varchar2(4000);
  cursor c1 is 
  select '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||' t from dual;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 bulk collect into v_text_array;
  for i in 1..v_text_array.count loop
    for j in 2..regexp_count(v_text_array(i),'\|\|') loop
      val := trim(',' from regexp_replace(regexp_substr(v_text_array(i),'[^\|]+',1,j),'!!',','));
      for k in 1..regexp_count(val,',')+1 loop
        --display to console or further process...
        dbms_output.put_line(regexp_substr(val,'[^,]+',1,k));
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for providing solution. But we can not consider it to constant(4). I've give only an example. In my code, it will increase to even more than 50 values. But the format remains same. If possible, kindly make it generic like checking the count and then executing ahead..

Comment: more than 50 separate values(columns) for each row?

Comment: Yes. Means we don't know the fix count. In production servers we have to create a generic code only. No hardcoding

Comment: Than separate columns is not an option.  Access "array" column with coma separated values and split it in e.g. pl/sql using loop

Comment: Ok.. But how to split and access those values using for loop.. Could you please add that functionality into your query. I shall be really thankful to you

Comment: Big Thanks to you.. Kindly tell me one more thing I have 3 variables: var1, var2, var3. So as per query, how to assign 3 values to 3 variables again and again like using variables insert the data. Again, reuse variable and insert the data.. Please help..thanks ...

Comment: add +1 before last loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102094/discussion-between-tans-and-piotr-siekierski).

Answer (score 0):

The below one returns expected results:

```
with x as 
(select '2322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||' str
 from dual),
 y as (
select regexp_substr(str,'[^||]+[!!]*', 1, level) str from x
    where level > 1
    connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^||]+[!!]*', 1, level) is not null
     )   
 select 
     regexp_replace (
      regexp_replace (
         regexp_replace(str, '^!!', '(') ,
          '!!$', ')'),   
          '[ ]*!![ ]*', ',')  str
   from y
```

Comment: One thing more is it, possible to excess each value separately.. I want some thing like executing a for loop till the count of total rows. Then from each row pick each value and assign to variable and process it. Then 2nd row and assign all 4 values to same variables and process it and so on...

Comment: I've tried the code with for loop. like 
for I in(your query)loop
dbms_output.put_line(I.STR);
end loop;
But STR is returning row by row. Is there something like STR[1] for accessing 123 and so on

Comment: Can you display 4 values into 4 columns. Because the total number of values in each row will remain same. In that case also there would be easy to access each values

Comment: Your query is ignoring spaces. Please replace [ ]*!![ ]*', ',' to  [/]*!![ ]*', ','

Comment: @Tans Just modify to your requirements. I don't know exactly what you need - I created solution for that what I can understand from your question. It may be starting point for your real task. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need apply twice the split on delimiter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378083/comma-separated-list).
Finally get the values (word) flat again using LISTAGG and finalize with some string concatenation.

I'm providing a complete example **with two input records, so it can scale for any number of your parsed lines**.

You may need to adjust the `T2`table limiting the number of splits. Some special handling is additionally needed if you can have NULL values in your keyword.

The query - commented below

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT 1 id,
    '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!|| ' col
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id,
    '22222ACCCC12Y||!!567!!word21  !!word22!! word23!!||!!789!!word24!!word25  !! word26!!||!!2345  !!word27!!word28!! 890!!|| ' col
  FROM dual
  ),
  t2 AS
  (SELECT rownum colnum
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level < 10
    /* (max) number of columns */
  ),
  t3 AS
  (SELECT t1.id,
    t2.colnum,
    regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^|]+', 1, t2.colnum) col
  FROM t1,
    t2
  WHERE regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^|]+', 1, t2.colnum) IS NOT NULL
  ),
  first_split AS
  ( SELECT id, colnum, col FROM t3 WHERE col LIKE '%!!%'
  ),
  second_split AS
  (SELECT t1.id,
    t1.colnum linenum,
    t2.colnum,
    regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^!]+', 1, t2.colnum) col
  FROM first_split t1,
    t2
  WHERE regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^!]+', 1, t2.colnum) IS NOT NULL
  ),
  agg_values AS
  (SELECT id,
    linenum,
    LISTAGG(col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY colnum) val_lst
  FROM second_split
  GROUP BY id,
    linenum
  )
SELECT id,
  'array['
  || row_number() over (partition BY ID order by linenum)
  || ']= ('
  ||val_lst
  ||')' array_text
FROM agg_values
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Yields as requested

```
    ID ARRAY_TEXT   
     1 array[1]= (123, word1, word2, word3)   
     1 array[2]= (789, word4, word5, word6)      
     1 array[3]= (2345, word7, word8, 890)        
     2 array[1]= (567, word21, word22, word23)        
     2 array[2]= (789, word24, word25, word26)         
     2 array[3]= (2345, word27, word28, 890)
```

This is the result of the **first_split** query. You break the data in lines.

```
ID     COLNUM COL
---------- ---------- ------------------------------------------
1          2 !!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!
1          3 !!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!
1          4 !!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!
2          2 !!567!!word21  !!word22!! word23!!
2          3 !!789!!word24!!word25  !! word26!!
2          4 !!2345  !!word27!!word28!! 890!!
```

The **second_split** query breaks the lines in word.

```
ID    LINENUM     COLNUM COL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2          1 123
1          2          2 word1
1          2          3 word2
1          2          4 word3
1          3          1 789
1          3          2 word4
1          3          3 word5
.....
```

The rest is LISTAGG to get the csv keyword list and a ROW_NUMBER function to get nice sequential array_ids

If you want to extract the values in separate columns use **PIVOT** instead of LISTAGG. The drawback is that you must adjust the query for the actual number of the values.

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT 1 id,
    '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!|| ' col
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id,
    '22222ACCCC12Y||!!567!!word21  !!word22!! word23!!||!!789!!word24!!word25  !! word26!!||!!2345  !!word27!!word28!! 890!!|| ' col
  FROM dual
  ),
  t2 AS
  (SELECT rownum colnum
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level < 10
    /* (max) number of columns */
  ),
  t3 AS
  (SELECT t1.id,
    t2.colnum,
    regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^|]+', 1, t2.colnum) col
  FROM t1,
    t2
  WHERE regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^|]+', 1, t2.colnum) IS NOT NULL
  ),
  first_split AS
  ( SELECT id, colnum, col FROM t3 WHERE col LIKE '%!!%'
  ),
  --select * from first_split order by 1,2,3;
  second_split AS
  (SELECT t1.id,
    t1.colnum linenum,
    t2.colnum,
    regexp_substr(t1.col,'[^!]+', 1, t2.colnum) col
  FROM first_split t1,
    t2
  WHERE regexp_substr(t1.col, '[^!]+', 1, t2.colnum) IS NOT NULL
  ),
  pivot_values AS
  (SELECT  *
  FROM second_split PIVOT (MAX(col) col FOR (colnum) IN (1 AS "K1", 2 AS "K2", 3 AS "K3", 4 AS "K4"))
  )
SELECT id,
  row_number() over (partition BY ID order by linenum) AS array_id,
  K1_COL,
  K2_COL,
  K3_COL,
  K4_COL
FROM pivot_values
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

gives the *relational* view

```
ID   ARRAY_ID K1_COL   K2_COL   K3_COL   K4_COL
---------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- --------
1          1 123      word1    word2     word3
1          2 789      word4    word5     word6
1          3 2345     word7    word8     890
2          1 567      word21   word22    word23
2          2 789      word24   word25    word26
2          3 2345     word27   word28    890
```

Comment: In your case also result is removing the spaces .. For eg.. rather than "word1     " it was giving "word1"..
I

Comment: is it, possible to excess each value separately.. I want some thing like executing a for loop till the count of arrays . Then from each array pick each value and assign to variable like 123 to variable1, word1 to variable2 and process it. Then 2nd array and assign all 4 values to same variables and process it and so on...

Comment: Can you display 4 values into 4 columns. Because the total number of values in each row will remain same. In that case also there would be easy to access each values

Comment: @Tans I updated the query not to eat the spaces and added a query using PIVOT the get the values in separated columns.

Comment: Is it possible to make the code generic. You've considered the K1 to K4.. But I've shared the example only. In real scenario the values will increase or decrease.

Comment: @Tans if you want to access the values in columns (like with PIVOT) you need to define each column, i.e. you need adjust the query.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, '12322ABCD124A||!!123!!word1  !!word2!! word3!!||!!789!!word4!!word5  !! word6!!||!!2345  !!word7!!word8!! 890!!||' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '12322ABCD124A||!!321!!word1a  !!word2a!! word3a!!||!!987!!word4a!!word5a  !! word6a!!||!!5432  !!word7a!!word8a!! 098!!||' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,
       grp_no,
       CAST(
         MULTISET(
           SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+?)\s*!', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
           FROM    DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+?)\s*!' )
         )
         AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
       ) AS words
FROM   (
  SELECT  id,
          COLUMN_VALUE AS grp_no,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\|([^|]+)\|', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS text
  FROM    table_name t,
          TABLE(
            CAST(
              MULTISET(
                SELECT  LEVEL
                FROM    DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\|([^|]+)\|' )
              )
              AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
            )
          )
) t;
```

**Results**:

```
       ID     GRP_NO WORDS
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------
         1          1 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('123','word1','word2','word3')
         1          2 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('789','word4','word5','word6')
         1          3 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('2345','word7','word8','890')
         2          1 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('321','word1a','word2a','word3a')
         2          2 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('987','word4a','word5a','word6a')
         2          3 SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('5432','word7a','word8a','098')
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id,
       grp_no,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+)!', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS Word1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+)!', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS Word2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+)!', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS Word3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.text, '!\s*([^!]+)!', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS Word4
FROM   (
  SELECT  id,
          COLUMN_VALUE AS grp_no,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\|([^|]+)\|', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS text
  FROM    table_name t,
          TABLE(
            CAST(
              MULTISET(
                SELECT  LEVEL
                FROM    DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\|([^|]+)\|' )
              )
              AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
            )
          )
) t;
```

**Results**:

```
ID   GRP_NO WORD1   WORD2   WORD3   WORD4
---- ------ ------- ------- ------- -------
   1      1 123     word1   word2   word3        
   1      2 789     word4   word5   word6 
   1      3 2345    word7   word8   890    
   2      1 321     word1a  word2a  word3a
   2      2 987     word4a  word5a  word6a   
   2      3 5432    word7a  word8a  098
```